# Claim $\lim_{\delta \to 0} E\int_{|y| \le 1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}| u(x)-u(x+\delta y)|^2\rho(y) \,dx\,dy = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, with $u \in L^2( \Omega \times\mathbb{R}^d)$. Let $\rho$ be the standard mollifier approximation to Dirac's delta dunction defined on $\mathbb{R}^d$ supported in $\{ y \,|\, |y|\le 1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$.
>    I would like to show $$\lim_{\delta \to 0} E\int_{|y| \le 1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}| u(x)-u(x+\delta y)|^2\rho(y) \,dx\,dy = 0$$

I know $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}| u(x)-u(x+\delta y)|^2 \to 0$ as $\delta \to 0$ uniformly using transalation continuity in $L^p$ , and thus we have $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_{|y| \le 1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}| u(x)-u(x+\delta y)|^2\rho(y) \,dx\,dy = 0$. After this how can I interchange the limit with expection? Maybe somehow Dominated convergence theorem can be used.

Comment: I take it you mean $\rho$ is a smooth approximation to Dirac's delta function, but you said it's "the standard" one. I didn't know there was one that's singled out to be called that. Do you mean a Gaussian density function?

Comment: oh .... Maybe you mean $\rho$ is supported on $|y| \le 1.$ So it would _not_ be a Gaussian density. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes sir $\rho$ is supported in $[-1,1]$, approximation to Delta function.

Comment: You have $x+\delta y\in\mathbb R^d.$ So either $\delta \in \mathbb R^d$ and $y \in \mathbb R$ or $\delta \in \mathbb R$ and $y \in \mathbb R^d.$ I had assumed the latter until you said $\rho$ is supported in $[-1,1].$ Maybe it doesn't matter to the bottom line, but it seems hazardous not to be explicit about that. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$. Let me be more explicit.

Comment: So that means $y\in \mathbb R^d,$ so $\rho$ is not supported in $[-1,1],$ but maybe in $\{ y\in\mathbb R^d : \|y\|\le 1\}. \qquad$

Comment: Yes, sorry about these errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

$$|u(x)-u(x+\delta y)|^2 \leq 2|u(x)|^2 + 2|u(x+\delta y)|^2$$

we find

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |u(x)-u(x+\delta y)| \, dx \leq 2 \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |u(x)|^2 \, dx + 2 \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |u(x+\delta y)|^2 \, dx = 4 \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |u(x)|^2 \, dx.$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align*} \int_{|y| \leq 1} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |u(x)-u(x+\delta y)|^2 \varrho(y) \, dx \, dy \leq 4 \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |u(x)|^2 \, dx\right) \int_{|y| \leq 1} \varrho(y) \,dy. \end{align*}$$

As $u \in L^2(\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^d)$ the right-hand side is an integrable dominating function (which does not depend on $\delta$). Since you have already shown that the left-hand side converges to $0$ as $\delta \to 0$ we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that

$$\mathbb{E} \int_{|y| \leq 1} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |u(x)-u(x+\delta y)|^2 \varrho(y) \, dx \, dy \xrightarrow[]{\delta \to 0} 0.$$